# Can I Skip Junit Tests if other tests fail?

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm using **Junit** to run tests with **Seleniun WebDriver**.  I'm trying to split up my tests into function area for better error reporting.  I've created tests to test Page load/moving documents to other workflows.  If a page load test fails, or a workflow move fails I want to skip the subsequent page/workflow tests.

if a Test A fails how can I skip either the rest of the tests in the class or running tests in Class B?

**NOTE:**
I realize what I'm asking is "bad Practice* for *UNIT TESTS*. However, I'm actually using Junit for *Integration* and/or *Automation* Testing. (Depending on your definition.)
I've already found `@Suite.SuiteClasses`, and `@FixMethodOrder` to order my test classes and test methods.  I'm trying to order them to run logically, testing the page load, first, then each feature of the page as a seperate test. Some of the features, move the information to other pages, meanining other classes. 1 of my classes can take over 1/2 hour to finish.  If the pre-req tests fail, I'd like to short circuite the "Dependent" tests, in order to get my results/report sooner.

Comment: why does the test A fail?

Comment: Test A could fail because the Documument didn't move to the other workflow properly, or that not all of the elements I expect to see on the page are there. (depends on the test)

Comment: JUnit does not execute the tests in a determined order. So you will not be able to ensure that a certain test is run before another.

Comment: You should never. Good practice is to get a full pass (period).You should arrange your JUnit tests in such order that all the tests follow each other logically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you switching to TestNG. Check [this](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) out.

Btw:When I used to work with Java - almost one year ago - I didn't find such a solution for JUnit.

Answer (score 3):

By using [Junit's Assume](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html)within the @Before or @Test methods, you can skip the current test by using either

1. [Assume#assumeTrue(boolean)](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html#assumeTrue(boolean)) for any depended tests that failed. You can skip the current test by calling Assume.assumeTrue(false)
2. [Assume#assumeNoException(Throwable)](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html#assumeNoException(java.lang.Throwable)) for skippable tests and skip the current test by passing the [AssumptionVoilated](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/AssumptionViolatedException.html) exception when the other test was skipped.

Here's an example:

```
public class Tests{
    @Test
    public void test1(){
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        try{
            test1();
        }catch(AssertionError failExcep){
            //test1 failed, skip this test
            Assume.assumeTrue(false);
        }catch(AssumptionVoilationException skipExcep){
            //test1 was skipped, skip this test
            Assume.assumeNoException(skipExcep);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

This particular example would run test1() twice, but by adding @FixMethodOrder and catching the any error thrown during test1 to be referenced in test2; we could circumvent that issue.

Also this example does not cover any other exception type that test1() could throw, e.g. NullPointerException. Editing the AssumptionVoilationException catch clause to Exception will allow test2 to be skipped on any exception. If you also want to catch Error or Throwable just add a catch clause and put in Assume.assumeTrue(false) like AssertionError. Or you could just throw [AssumptionViolatedException](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/AssumptionViolatedException.html)

Here's the dummy proof version

```
@FixMethodOrder
public class Tests{

    private Optional<Throwable> testOneThrown;

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        try{
            ...
        }catch(Throwable t){
            // test1 throw something, catching it for test2() reference
            testOneThrown = Optional.of(t);
            /*
             * still throwing it for junit normal functions and
             * in case test2 ran independently
             */
            throw t;
        }
        //Ran successfully, making reference non-null but empty
        testOneThrown = Optional.empty();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        try{
            if(testOneThrown == null){
                // test1 did not run, thus needs to run
                test1();
            }else if(testOneThrown.isPresent()){
                // test1 ran and threw something
                throw testOneThrown.get();
            }
            //test1 ran and throw nothing
        }catch(Throwable thrown){
            /*
             * something was throw in test1, test1 could have
             * failed, could have been skipped, etc. thus skip 
             * this test.
             */
            throw new AssumptionViolatedException("Dependency on test1 failed.", thrown);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: JUnit typically creates a new instance of the test wrapper class for each test, so I think `testOneThrown` should be `static`.

Comment: I would assume it also depends on the junit version; as when I was testing the code above, I had a console printer to ensure test1 ran once. So if it did run multiple times, I would see. And because junit makes no promise about how it will run the test cases, I'm sure they did altered it to your point.

Answer (score 0):

You could try manipulating the tests via the Rules interface, they have an example here:
http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/11/18/a-junit-rule-to-conditionally-ignore-tests/

That might be a good starting point.